# WebStorm on Mac : No administrative area found under /Users/[Name]

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

After a while, using WebStorm, when I try to rename a folder or a file I get this error in the `Rename` pop up window.

`java.io.IOException : com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: No administrative area found under /Users/[Name]/..../[ProjectName]`

To fix the issue I have to use `Invalidate Caches and restart...` option but it is not very convenient.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: similar is is tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170126, please follow it for updates

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all of your `.idea`. folders and reopen IntelliJ.